# How to use the subquery EXISTS in Loopback?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have two models `Reference` and `Product`, `Reference` has many `Product` and I need to run the next query (with some Loopback's method) so I doesn't get the empty products.

```
SELECT DISTINCT R.id
FROM Reference R
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT id FROM Product P
  WHERE P.referenceId = R.id AND P.stock > 0
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is your *question*? What is "Loopback" referring to?

Comment: Hi Erwin, I'm talking about of Loopback Node Framework for APIs from Strongloop.

Comment: The tag [loopback], though being the same word, refers to something else.

Comment: Thanks Erwin. Edited, Any help for this?

Comment: Sorry, don't know loopbackjs. But you don't need the `DISTINCT` if `id` is UNIQUE in table `Reference`.

Answer (score 0):

Currently is not posible to query a model filtering based on a related model property using the built-in methods/query language, check this [issue](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/517). So you will have to execute your sql using the datasource connector. That is for example if you have a model file called Reference.js:

```
var dbConnection = Reference.dataSource.connector;
dbConnection.execute(yourSql, [], function (err, references) {});
```

The result will be an array of objects with only the id property. Check [this](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Executing-native-SQL.html)

Another option could be do the relation bidirectional (Product belongs to Reference) and query for products having stock > 0, but you are going to have to group the repeated values:

```
var Product = Reference.app.models.Product;
Product.find({where: {stock: {gt:0}}, fields: {referenceId:true}}, function (err, prods) {})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Directly with raw SQL is not possible because I need active some hooks and more complex getter/setter. The second option is good but the problem is the response:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "products": []
  }
]
```

Te response includes the references with empty products anyway.

Comment: If that is the response you are getting you are querying the Reference model (with some include filter), in the example of the second option i'm querying the Product model.